# "Building site" vs. "construction site"

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is *building site* the British English equivalent of *construction site* in American English, and is it used in American English?

Answer (score 2):

As an American English (Texan) speaker, "construction site" is a tad more familiar, but either phrase would communicate the concept just fine.

Comment: I could imagine a "building site" being designated and called that even before construction actually begins.  So perhaps there is a slight difference.

Comment: Agreed..."construction site" tends to imply that construction is actually underway.

Answer (score 2):

Building site is definitely the normal phrase here (Scotland).  Construction site *might* be used for a non-building site - i.e. civil engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely say so. I (as a Brit) would never say construction site and I don't think that I have never heard an American refer to a building site.